# Why does the solution to a coding challenge seem so much more complex than mine, while mine is simpler?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am following a C++ course which has one challenge in each section. For the most recent challenge, we were to take out three different types of data from a text file, where in one line there are three data types each separated by a tab (only two tabs, you will see).

```
1\tBox of 64 Pixels\t64 RGB pixels in a decorative box
2\tSense of Humor\tEspecially dry. Imported from England.
3\tBeauty\tInner beauty. No cosmetic surgery required!
4\tBar Code\tUnused. In original packaging.
```

The first type is the SKU number, the second is the name, and the third is the description. You have to place all this information in a struct.

My solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct CI
{
  int sku = 0;
  string name = "";
  string desc = "";
};

const int MAXSTRING = 1024;

int main()
{
  const char *itemsPath = "items.txt";

  FILE *items = fopen(itemsPath, "r");

  CI changed1;
  CI changed2;
  CI changed3;
  CI changed4;
  vector<CI> changed = {changed1, changed2, changed3, changed4};

  vector<string> lines = vector<string>();

  char buffer[MAXSTRING];

  int tab = 0;
  int counter = 0;

  while (fgets(buffer, MAXSTRING, items))
  {
    lines.push_back(buffer);
  }

  for (string &s : lines)
  {
    for (char &c : s)
    {
      if (c == '\t')
      {
        tab++;
        continue;
      }

      if (tab == 0)
      {
        changed[counter].sku = c - '0';
      }
      else if (tab == 1)
      {
        changed[counter].name += c;
      }
      else if (tab == 2)
      {
        changed[counter].desc += c;
      }
    }
    tab = 0;
    counter++;

    if (counter == 4)
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    cout << "sku: " << changed[i].sku << ", name: " << changed[i].name << ", desc: " << changed[i].desc;
  }

  fclose(items);

  return 0;
}
```

The actual solution:

```cpp
// 08_solution.cpp by Bill Weinman <http://bw.org/>
// updated 2002-07-23
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

constexpr size_t maxstring = 1024; // size of line buffer
constexpr size_t name_size = 32;   // size of name string
constexpr size_t desc_size = 128;  // size of description string
constexpr const char *filename = "/Users/billw/Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap08/items.txt";
constexpr size_t max_split = 15;
constexpr char tab_char = '\t';

struct Item
{
  int sku;              // stock keeping unit
  char name[name_size]; // item name
  char desc[desc_size]; // item description
};

// str_seps(s) -- returns an array where each element
// represents the position of a separator in the string
// first element is a count
size_t *str_seps(const char *s, size_t len)
{
  static size_t indicies[max_split + 1];
  size_t &count = indicies[0];
  if (len < 3)
    return indicies;
  for (size_t &z : indicies)
    z = 0; // zero out the array

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if (s[i] == tab_char)
    {
      ++count;
      indicies[count] = i;
      if (count >= max_split)
        break;
    }
  }
  return indicies;
}

int main()
{
  char buf[maxstring]; // buffer for reading lines in file

  // open the file
  FILE *fr = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (!fr)
  {
    const char *errstr = strerror(errno);
    printf("cannot open file (%d): %s\n", errno, errstr);
    return 1;
  }

  // read loop
  while (fgets(buf, maxstring, fr))
  {
    size_t len = strnlen(buf, maxstring);
    if (len <= 5)
      continue;

    // trim the newline from the end of the string
    if (buf[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
      buf[len - 1] = 0;
      --len;
    }

    size_t *split3 = str_seps(buf, len);
    if (split3[0] < 2)
      break;
    buf[split3[1]] = buf[split3[2]] = 0; // change separators to terminators

    Item current_item;
    current_item.sku = atoi(buf);
    strncpy(current_item.name, buf + split3[1] + 1, name_size - 1);
    strncpy(current_item.desc, buf + split3[2] + 1, desc_size - 1);
    printf("sku: %d, name: %s, desc: %s\n", current_item.sku, current_item.name, current_item.desc);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDITED: To be specific, is my code unsafe, and is the check to see if the file has been opened or not:

```cpp
  if (!fr)
  {
    const char *errstr = strerror(errno);
    printf("cannot open file (%d): %s\n", errno, errstr);
    return 1;
  }
```

needed.

Comment: why does some code you did not write appear more complex to you than code you wrote yourself? Thats a common effect: code that you wrote yourself always looks simpler than somebody else code. Code written by someone else takes effort to read and understand. Wait a month or two and your own code will look like it was written by someone else ;)

Comment: IMO the second version is a no go. The author wrote C code and sells it as C++ code.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense...I shouldn't call it more complex as it is more complex to me. Thanks! But still is there anyway you could help me understand that code easily or tell me if my code is unsafe or not good.

This is replying to @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: for reviews of working code there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Though I don't know how it will be received there to ask for a review of code you did not write. "is this code good" is purely opinion based and offtopic here

Comment: if there is something specific you don't understand you can reword the question to make it more focused

Comment: Kk thanks lemme edit it then to ask one specific question I had

Comment: Code Review is only for code that's written by the asker or under their maintenance, so only the first version can be reviewed there, not the "actual solution".

Comment: I wasn't asking anyone to review the 'actual solution' (I should call it bill's code). I just wanted to know if MY solution was unsafe. I know there are stuff like data leaks or leaving files open is bad, but don't know much in depth about it, so I wanted to know if I have unnoticintly did one of those mistakes.

Oh and @463035818_is_not_a_number I edited the question to be specific.

Comment: "still is there anyway you could help me understand that code easily" is basically asking for a review of the code, nevermind...

Comment: Your code has the line `using namespace std;`  The purpose of namespaces is to prevent name collisions, but by adding the using line you remove that function.

Comment: If the solution was last updated in 2002 why is it using C++11 constexpr?  Something fishy here.

Comment: You do need to check whether `fopen` succeeds, if it fails then it returns a null pointer, if you then try to pass that pointer to `fread` your program will have undefined behaviour.

If this code was written in c++ rather than mostly c it would be shorter, simpler and safer: https://godbolt.org/z/neb34EnvW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hint on why it looks odd is at the very beginning:

```
// updated 2002-07-23
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
```

So 20 year old code, using only the C library, might not be great C++.

On the other hand, code like:

```
  CI changed1;
  CI changed2;
  CI changed3;
  CI changed4;
  vector<CI> changed = {changed1, changed2, changed3, changed4};
```

is probably also only obvious to the person writing it. :-)

*Guess* it means the same as `vector<CI> changed(4);`, but I had to think about it for a while.